# How do I get context coloring in Mac OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, color-theme

When I ssh into a remote server from my terminal in Mac OS X Snow Leopard, I get all sorts of great context coloring. It makes it much easier to edit files in `vi`, gives good contrast when I `ls -al`, etc.

However, my local terminal doesn't have any of that context coloring. Is there a place I can choose those settings or some statements I can throw into my `.profile` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use bash, you can put this into your `~/.profile`:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

For vi, just enter `:syntax on`.

---

#### What are the color values?

The `LSCOLORS` specify the color values of the different items:

```
a = black
b = red
c = green
d = brown
e = blue
f = magenta
g = cyan
h = light gray
x = default
```

This works better for a **dark background**:

```
export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
```

This works better for a **bright background**:

```
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
```

---

#### What are the positions of the colors?

Those are the positions of the values, in the order as they appear in `LSCOLORS`:

```
DIR
SYM_LINK
SOCKET
PIPE
EXE
BLOCK_SP
CHAR_SP
EXE_SUID
EXE_GUID
DIR_STICKY
DIR_WO_STICKY
```

<sub>[Source](http://www.napolitopia.com/2010/03/lscolors-in-osx-snow-leopard-for-dummies/)</sub>

Comment: You have this answer macro'ed by now, right?

Comment: Huh? First time I've written an answer about that..